# How to freeze more than 5 column in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

How to freeze more than 5 column in google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't as of yet. According to Google's support page, [Rows and columns: Freezing columns and rows](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54813):

> **Freezing Columns**
>
> There are also two methods to freeze
>   columns in a spreadsheet:
>
> - The Column Bar is a vertical bar that separates active columns from
>     frozen ones. Using its handle (found
>     at top, by the column headers), you
>     can drag the Column Bar left or right
>     to the last column you'd like to
>     freeze, **5 columns maximum.**
> - Click the Tools tab and then click the "Freeze columns" drop-down menu.
>     From the menu, select the number of
>     columns you want to freeze, **5
>     columns maximum.**

Comment: and we canonly freeze first 5 column and row what if i want to free column 8 only

Answer (score 13):

The freeze menu item now lists the first two rows/columns or all the way up to the currently selected cell:

[image: screen shot]

This can also be done by **dragging the frozen column handle at the top of the column**:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Great answer.  It looks like Google has changed the interface now since you posted - in the menu it now allows you to freeze one or two columns, or all up to the row/column you are currently on.

Comment: This should now be Best Answer.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac, you can now drag the frozen column handle past the 5th column.

Comment: This is not a Mac thing, works also on Linux and Windows. Look @KyleMit answer.